# Rolle's theorem and Functions

Tags: functions, derivatives, roots

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a 3-times differentiable function and has at least 5 distinct zeros. Which of the following necessarily has 2 distinct zeros?

A. $ f + 6f' + 12f'' + 8f''' $
B. $ f''' - 3f'' + 3f' - f$
C. $f''' + 3 \sqrt 2 f'' + 6f' +2 \sqrt2 f $

My idea:

Since the function has 5 roots, according to Rolle's theorem, $f'''$ must have at least 2 roots. But how do we get to a function which has at least two distinct roots?
I know though that option A can be expressed as $ g'''(x)/(e^{x/2}) $ where $g(x) = 8f(x)e^{x/2} $.

Comment: If I'm correct reading the question, you don't need a function with exactly two roots. Just two or more roots.

Comment: In what you wrote.the third derivative has at least two zeros instead of three.

Comment: Yes, Both of you are right. Edited

Comment: A. is the correct answer precisely by the technique you stated. Indeed, this was problem B$1$ on last year's Putnam.

Comment: @Rellek can you please explain the answer? I didn't quite understand. First of all, how do you go back an get the function that describes this? Is this the only function that describes this situation?